# View SQL with STRUCT fields description

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want a create view SQL script where I can add description of fields under a struct column. Something like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MyDataset.MyView
(
  id OPTIONS(description="unique ID"),
  location STRUCT<id OPTIONS(description="Location ID for Event"), 
                  description OPTIONS(description="Loc Desc")> OPTIONS(description="Event Location Record")
) AS
 SELECT id,
   location
 FROM location_table
;
```

This SQL throws me the following error,

> Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got keyword STRUCT